Телеграмм бот на JS + HTML
Всем привет.У меня есть сайт на html/css/js , и есть телеграмм бот на Node JS.В телеграмм боте есть функция, которую надо вызвать через код сайта, как мне это сделать?

Это так не работает. Вам нужно связать ваш веб-сайт с отдельным приложением на nodejs и как-то с ним взаимодействовать.
